# Creating line which connects point to closest line in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have an area divided into several districts which each have their own centroid. I also have a road network of the area. I want to connect the centroids with the road network by connecting them to the closest line segment from the road network.

Actually what i want is described in here: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011815.
But when I follow the steps I am just left with an empty shapefile.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Please list the precise steps that you performed rather than expecting potential answerers to follow a link in order to synthesize your question.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant workflow, but I would carry out the analysis thus:

1. I would give each point a unique identifier by creating a new string field and setting it to be something like the word "Point" and the FID for each point. I personally like generating unique codes, rather than using FIDs.
2. I would use the Near tool, firstly, to get the X and Y coordinates of the nearest point on your road network for each point. The Near tool adds this as two new fields to an existing featureclass/shapefile if "location" is selected for the tool.
3. I would then export the attribute table of your points dataset, and create an event layer from the Near X and Y coordinates within this table.
4. I would then export the events layer as a new featureclass or shapefile.

Consider what we have created at this point. We have two sets of points, one being your original dataset and the second being the nearest point on the road network, as per the dataset created from the events layer in step 3. Each district centroid now has a corresponding point in the second dataset with the same ID, created in step 1, as the original point, but sitting on the road network.

5. Merge the two point datasets into a new dataset. Configure the tool to merge the unique identifier fields of the two datasets, so that there will be two points per unique identifier (from step 1) in the ID field.
6. Use the Points To Line tool to create lines between the points. The "Line_Field" option should be set to your unique identifier field, so that only points sharing the same identifier will be converted to lines.

Comment: What you are suggesting is a shorter version of what @S Berlo already tried. See hyperlinked post in OP

Comment: I find the methodology set out in the link to be needlessly complex for the task required. I also wouldn't simply clone the Object ID field to make a unique identifier, as a text ID makes it a lot easier to trace issues down the line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it gave me a better understanding in all the steps. I think i know what the problem is: Creating an event layer from the Near X and Y coordinates seems to be the problem. If I do this it creates a shapefile which has an attribute table, but it doesn't show the points on the map. Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It could be as simple as the events layer being drawn behind the road network? Do the coordinates seem sensible, and can you zoom to a single point to inspect it?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. Even when I only turn on the newly created layer there is nothing to see. Even when I select a feature from the attribute table and I press 'zoom to selected' there is nothing to see.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Do the coordinates the Near tool produces look sensible?

Comment: I am not sure what they should look like, but here is an example:
Near_X: 702151,714048
Near_Y: 9298717,166748

The other values are near the example values, so I think that should be OK. Or should those values look different?